# is iconv_set_encoding deprecated in php 5.4.25?

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin

I have a magento website. which worked find until my hosting server upgraded its php version to 5.4.25.Now i'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_get_encoding() in /home/dbname/public_html/Magento/mysite/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php on line 520
```

why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should uncomment `extension=iconv.so` in php.ini. That would enable the function